# python 2.7: @ (g/s)etter def fails derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to use the '@' property.  My code is:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
class person(node): #
    def __init__(self, name):
        #node.__init__(self,name)
        self.tag = name
    @property
    def tag(self):
        return self._tag
    @tag.setter
    def tag(self, val):
        if type(val) == str: 
            self._tag = val
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid value for name")

p =person("a")
p.tag=12
print p.tag
```

This throws an exception in python3 (as it should) but runs to completion in python 2(printing 12)

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Python2 is no longer maintained, so if this is a bug, it's not likely to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code in python3 is the `print` statement. In python3, `print` must use parenthesis, as in `print(p.tag)`.

Other than that, your code is fine. When assigning 12 to tag, it fails with the exception "Invalid value for name". When assigning a string to tag (e.g. 'b'), it works fine.